# Basic JS Canvas Game

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm working on a very basic JS canvas based game that's kind of a cross between missile defense and space invaders and am in need of some help.

I've got a little turret at the bottom of the screen that shoots circles from the barrel but, for some reason, the most recently shot circle seems to have a second circle lagging right behind it. However, when another shot is fired, the lagging circle disappears from behind the original and then appears behind the new shot.
Also, I have a square that comes down of the screen that represents what will be an alien invader that is acting oddly. The alien flies down 250 pixels and then begins to move in a square path until it is destroyed. It seems like the square representing the alien changes size as it moves along the edges of the square path which obviously should not happen.

Besides these two problems, I'd love to hear any suggestions you have about the code. I've never used JavaScript before and really don't code much in general so any help/guidance is appreciated.

This is a working demo: http://jsbin.com/ehezuj/1/edit

This is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Space Game Demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section>
            <div>
                <canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="600">
                    Your browser does not support HTML5.
                </canvas>
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
//Start of script
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var x = 400;
var y = 0;
var direction = 0;
var mouseDown = false;
var gloop;
var shots = new Array;
var aliens = new Array;
aliens.push(new basicAlien());
var playerTurret = new (function() { //turret object
    var that = this;
    that.draw = function() {
        ctx.fillStyle = "white";
        ctx.strokeStyle = "white";
        ctx.rect(380, 540, 40, 60); //draw base
        ctx.fill();

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(400, 540, 20, Math.PI, 2*Math.PI);
        ctx.fill();

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.lineWidth="10";
        ctx.moveTo(400, 540);
        var tempX, tempY, temp;
        temp = getTrajectory(x, y);
        tempX = 35 * temp[0]; tempY = 35 * temp[1];
        ctx.lineTo(tempX + 400, 540 - tempY);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
});

function basicAlien() {
    var that = this;
    that.step = 0; that.bottom = false;
    that.vel = 2;
    that.pos = [(Math.random() * 740) + 30, -10];
    that.move = function() {
        if (that.pos[1] >= 250) {that.bottom = true;}
        if (!that.bottom) {
            that.pos[1] += that.vel;
        }
        else {
            if (that.step < 20) {
                that.pos[0] += that.vel;
            }
            else if (that.step < 40) {
                that.pos[1] -= that.vel;
            }
            else if (that.step < 60) {
                that.pos[0] -= that.vel;
            }
            else {
                that.pos[1] += that.vel;
            }
            that.step = (that.step+1)%80;
        }
    }
    that.draw = function() {
        ctx.fillStyle = "white";
        ctx.rect(that.pos[0] - 10, that.pos[1] - 5, 20, 10);
        ctx.fill();
    }
};

function shotObject(shotX, shotY) {
    var that = this;
    that.traj = getTrajectory(shotX, shotY);
    that.vel = 10;
    that.pos = [400, 540];
    that.draw = function() {
        ctx.fillStyle = "white";
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(that.pos[0], that.pos[1], 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.fill();
    }
    that.move = function() {
        that.pos[0] += that.vel * that.traj[0];
        that.pos[1] -= that.vel * that.traj[1];
        if (that.pos[0] < -10 || that.pos[0] > 810 || that.pos[1] < -10 || that.pos[1] > 610) {
            shots.splice(shots.indexOf(that), 1);
        }
    }
};

function getTrajectory(coordx, coordy) {
    var tempX, tempY, neg = false;
    if (coordx == 400)  {
        if (coordy <= 540) {
            direction = degToRad(90);
        }
        else {
            direction = degToRad(270);
        }
    }
    else {
        direction = Math.atan((540 - coordy)/(coordx - 400));
        if (coordx < 400) {
            neg = true;
        }        
    }
    tempX = Math.cos(direction);
    tempY = Math.sin(direction);
    if (neg) {
        tempX = -tempX;
        tempY = -tempY;
        neg = false;
    }
    return [tempX, tempY];
};

function degToRad(angle) {
    return angle * (Math.PI/180);
}; //end degToRad()

function getMousePos(canvas, e) {
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
        x: e.clientX - rect.left,
        y: e.clientY - rect.top
    };
};

function process() {
    for (var i = 0; i < shots.length; i++) {
        shots[i].move();
    };
    for (var i = 0; i < aliens.length; i++) {
        aliens[i].move();
    };
};

function draw() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    playerTurret.draw();
    for (var i = 0; i < shots.length; i++) {
        shots[i].draw();
    };
    for (var i = 0; i < aliens.length; i++) {
        aliens[i].draw();
    };
}; //end draw()

function loop() {
    process();
    draw();
    gloop = setTimeout(loop, 25);
}; //end loop()

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    var mousePos = getMousePos(canvas, e);
    x = mousePos.x;
    y = mousePos.y;
}, false);

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    var mousePos = getMousePos(canvas, e);
    var shotX = mousePos.x;
    var shotY = mousePos.y;
    shots.push(new shotObject(shotX, shotY));
    mouseDown = true;
}, false);

canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
    mouseDown = false;
});

loop();

            </script>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about asking for a code review/beta test

Comment: Hint for debugging: you will propably have some guesses where the code behaves strange. Work with the console! do some `console.log(variable);` to see what certain variables are doing. Or use more advanced developer tools that have a run the code-step-by-step function.

Answer (score 4):

You have a few places where you are not calling `beginPath` and you should be.  The one in particular which is causing your extra shot and the elongation of the alien is in your player turret draw function:

```
ctx.beginPath();  // THIS LINE FIXES IT
ctx.fillStyle = "white";
ctx.strokeStyle = "white";
ctx.rect(380, 540, 40, 60); //draw base
ctx.fill();
```

Your `rect` here is being added to the path of last shot from the previous iteration and filling it as well.  Similarly, the alien's path from the previous iteration is filled causing a box to follow closely behind the alien, making it seem elongated in the direction it is currently moving (wider when left or right, taller when up or down)

http://jsfiddle.net/W3wKw/

**EDIT:**  [This demo](http://jsfiddle.net/W3wKw/1/) I think illustrates the issue pretty well.  This is the exact code from the initial question with just the colors changed.  Red is the turret fill/stroke, yellow is the alien fill and green is the shot fill.

Answer (score 2):

In draw() of basicAlien add ctx.beginPath();

```
that.draw = function() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(that.pos[0] - 10, that.pos[1] - 5, 20, 10);
    ctx.fill();
}
```